# Press a link on a webpage using Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I have this code where it goes to Minecraft.net and enters the username and password, and then goes to the profile page. I need to change the password on the account, which will be in cell A1 of the worksheet. I can't seem to figure out how to click the change password link. This is my code so far:

```
Dim IE As Object

Sub submitFeedback3()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
IE.Visible = True
IE.Navigate "https://minecraft.net/login"

Application.StatusBar = "Submitting"
' Wait while IE loading...
While IE.Busy
    DoEvents
Wend
' **********************************************************************
IE.Document.getElementById("username").Value = "dddddddd"
IE.Document.getElementById("password").Value = "ddd"
IE.Document.getElementById("signin").Click
'**********************************************************************
Application.StatusBar = "Form Submitted"

Set IE = Nothing

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Why not just `IE.Navigate *link_to_change_password*`?

Comment: Try .FireEvent ("onClick")

Comment: I tried to navigate to the link, but the link does not change when I go to the change password link

Answer (score 0):

If the `click` doesn't work then you could try to submit the html `form`.

```
' Add reference to Microsoft Internet Controls
' Add reference to Microsoft HTML Object Library

Set IE = New InternetExplorer
IE.Visible = True
IE.Navigate "https://minecraft.net/login"

While IE.Busy
    DoEvents
Wend

IE.Document.getElementById("username").Value = "dddddddd"
IE.Document.getElementById("password").Value = "ddd"

Dim htmlForm As HTMLFormElement
Set htmlForm = IE.Document.getElementById("loginForm")
htmlForm.submit
```

Comment: I tried, but I get the error "Compile Error: User-defined type not defined"

Comment: I prefer to add reference to ```Microsoft Internet Controls``` and ```Microsoft HTML Object Library``` so the variables are early bound and the intellisense is available (see the comment at the very beginning of the answer). Anyway you could declare the variables as variant and use late binding which will solve the problem ```User-defined type not defined```. [Adding a Reference to a Visual Basic Project](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683936(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: Hmm. I seem to be where I was before. When I go to the Minecraft profile page, the change password link isn't clicked